# Why does this code generate ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have a piece of code in Java (Android) that occasionally generates ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
String characterLevel = mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel() >= 
        MessageModel.CharacterLevels.length ? "Hyperion Overlord" : 
        MessageModel.CharacterLevels[mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel()];
```

The method mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel() is always 1 or more.

The MessageModel.CharacterLevels array is defined as follows and contains about 50 elements.

`public static final String[] CharacterLevels = { "Title", "Title" };`

The essence of the question is about gracefully defaulting to another source of the data if the size of the array has been exceeded.

I must be missing something. This is incorrect way to set a string to default to a string?

I've looked for solutions everywhere I can think of and I'm concerned I have just missing some basic flaw in the logic above.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: So I'm curious - assuming you solved it, what turned out to be the problem?

Comment: The crash comes from Star Traders RPG on the Google Play Developer Console, so I am only guessing that I fixed it. I was never able to replicate the crash myself. I made changes as suggested -- I now only called mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel() one time, in case the other threads are updating the character's stats. I also added a check to ensure level is not negative. CharacterLevels[] is never modified, so I skipped that. I also refactored the code similar to the suggestion you made below. Now I watch for 'Error Reports' and keep my fingers crossed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks logically equivalent to the following:

```
int level = mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel();
String[] arr = MessageModel.CharacterLevels;
String characterLevel = level < arr.length ? 
        arr[level] : 
        "Hyperion Overlord";
```

which will clearly only index into the array if it's within bounds.  I disagree with the other answers about the `-1` modifier to your array index, as your logic check should prevent the level from being too large for the array.

The only differences I can see in your original code (or things I can't see) that may cause the problem are (in order of likelihood):

1. You're calling `mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel()` more than once - if this changes with subsequent calls, it can be a source of errors. Perhaps it's 1 on the first call and 3 on the second?
2. `mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel()` may be returning a negative number - I'd add a check to make sure it's also `>= 0` before indexing into an array.
3. `MessageModel.CharacterLevels` may be something being accessed on multiple threads, and it's being modified between the length check and the access, causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String characterLevel = mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel() >= MessageModel.CharacterLevels.length-1 ? "Hyperion Overlord" : MessageModel.CharacterLevels[mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel()];
```

This should work, length is not 0 based, so you should go '-1' when calculate based on length.

Comment: Wouldn't the `>=` cover that? If length is 50, it will only index into the array if `CharacterLevel()` is 49 or less, which should be valid...

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts at 0, so you might want to use:

```
int index = mCharacterModel.CharacterLevel() - 1;
String characterLevel = index >= MessageModel.CharacterLevels.length ? "Hyperion Overlord" : MessageModel.CharacterLevels[index];
```

If the value is always 1 or more, you need to start with 0.
Another issue - you better not call the function `CharacterLevel()` twice and using the result. It is better to store the value in local variable and use it in both places.

Comment: Disagree on the -1 modifier to level. The logic is correct for making sure level doesn't exceed the array length (assuming the function returns the same value always).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15183844/836214) below for slightly rewritten version that makes this more obvious.

Comment: The -1 will help him get the 0 value, as it says the value is always 1 or more. As stated in my answer too, need to merge the calls for CharacterLevel.

Comment: But if the value of CharacterLevel is always strictly less than the array length - ie, not >= - then exceeding the array bounds (where the -1 would be useful) is not a problem.